# App Engine Java: syntax for setting query limit and start offset.

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a list of games in GAE datastore and I want to query fixed number of them, starting from a certain offset, i.e. get next 25 games starting form entry with id "75".

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager(); // from Google examples
Query query = pm.newQuery(Game.class); // objects of class Game are stored in datastore
query.setOrdering("creationDate asc");
/* querying for open games, not created by this player */
query.setFilter("state == Game.STATE_OPEN && serverPlayer.id != :playerId");
String playerId = "my-player-id";
List<Game> games = query.execute(playerId); // if there's lots of games, returned list has more entries, than user needs to see at a time
//...
```

Now I need to extend that query to fetch only 25 games and only games following entry with id "75". So the user can browse for open games, fetching only 25 of them at a time.
I know there's lots of examples for GAE datastore, but those all are mostly in Python, including sample code for setting limit on the query.
I am looking for a working Java code sample and couldn't find one so far.

Comment: Using a not-equal query to filter out (what I presume is) a single result is a waste of resources - the SDK has to execute two queries to satisfy this. Instead, filter out the single result you don't want from the returned result set.

Comment: There can be up to 5 games, that belong to the player in question. But practically when querying hundreds of games, 1 or 5 makes no difference, so you got the point, I will just move out that "!=" logic out of the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to facilitate paging via Query Cursors.  See: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html#Query_Cursors

From [the Google doc](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html#Query_Cursors):

```
public class ListPeopleServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
          throws ServletException, IOException {

        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        Query q = new Query("Person");
        PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
        int pageSize = 15;

        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        resp.getWriter().println("<ul>");

        FetchOptions fetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(pageSize);
        String startCursor = req.getParameter("cursor");

        // If this servlet is passed a cursor parameter, let's use it
        if (startCursor != null) {
            fetchOptions.startCursor(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(startCursor));
        }

        QueryResultList<Entity> results = pq.asQueryResultList(fetchOptions);
        for (Entity entity : results) {
            resp.getWriter().println("<li>" + entity.getProperty("name") + "</li>");
        }
        resp.getWriter().println("</ul>");

        String cursor = results.getCursor().toWebSafeString();

        // Assuming this servlet lives at '/people'
        resp.getWriter().println(
            "<a href='/people?cursor=" + cursor + "'>Next page</a>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... looks like what I need, except one limitation: **You cannot use cursors with queries that use the IN or != filter operators.** Example is using another API, not Persistence Manager, but that shouldn't be a problem, I'll try this and see if it works for me.

Comment: Thanks this is much clearer than the docs! Why can't they just provide a code sample with the section?

Comment: Ok, but why getOffset, getPrefetchSize, getChunkSize return null, once the cursor is set to fetchOptions?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for help. The cursors was the right answer.
The thing is that I am pretty much stuck with JDO and can't use DatastoreService, so I finally found this link:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries.html#Query_Cursors